# Split video into image frames in java

Tags: java, image, video

I would like to read a video(MPEG,AVI or any popular format) using Java code and split it into a no of frames(Jpeg),For instance splitting a 2sec video into 48 images(2X24 frames/sec).Is this possible in java.On hindsight i would also like to know if it is possible to create a video using an array of images(reconstruction of the video after editing the individual images).
Any help would be greatly appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can use ffmpeg.exe with java.

Comment: why this cannot be considered as an answer???

Answer (score 1):

You can use FFMPEG which is a open source C program build, and fastest video/audio processing library even used by most popular video sites.

use the exec method to call ffmpeg.

Answer (score 0):

You could use JMF (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-140239.html) for it.

Answer (score 0):

Easy with [velvet-video](https://github.com/zakgof/velvet-video):

Getting frames as images from a video file:

```
IVelvetVideoLib lib = VelvetVideoLib().getInstance();
try (IDemuxer demuxer = lib.demuxer(new File("/some/path/example.mp4"))) {
    IDecoderVideoStream videoStream = demuxer.videoStream(0);
    IFrame videoFrame;
    while ((videoFrame = videoStream.nextFrame()) != null) {
        BufferedImage image = videoFrame.image();
        // Use image as needed...
    }
}
```

Composing a video from image array

```
BufferedImage[] images = ...
IVelvetVideoLib lib = VelvetVideoLib().getInstance();
try (IMuxer muxer = lib.muxer("matroska")                    // specify you format
    .video(lib.videoEncoder("libaom-av1").bitrate(800000))   // specify you codec
    .build(new File("/some/path/output.mkv"))) {
         IEncoderVideoStream videoStream = muxer.videoStream(0);
         for (BufferedImage image : images) {
             videoStream.encode(image);
         }
}
```

Disclaimer: I'm the author of [velvet-video](https://github.com/zakgof/velvet-video)